# How can I store user entry twice?

Tags: c

I need to store an user entry twice.

For example:

```
for (conta_vetor=0;conta_vetor<50;conta_vetor++)
{
    printf("Digite o %d número:\n",conta_vetor);
    scanf("%d", &vetor[conta_vetor]);

}
```

The user entry must be stored on the vector position and on a new adress, using the same scanf.

How can i do that?

Comment: `*new_address = vetor[conta_vetor];`

Comment: Would you explain your question more clear?

Comment: I need to read the user entries until they type -1.  But how can I use two "for" for that? It simply doesnt work, because the conta_vetor dont stores the real number typed by the user.

Comment: Using while (conta_vetor >=0) dont work because the conta_vetor stores the vector position...

Comment: After you've read the data into one set of variables, copy the information into the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments:

```
int x;
int conta_vetor = 0;

for (;;)
{
    printf("Digite o %d número:\n",conta_vetor);
    scanf("%d", &x);
    if (x != -1)
      vetor[conta_vetor++] = x;
    else
      break;
}
```